# Understanding adding to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to add items to a dictionary, as an inventory list:

```
inventory = []
item = {}

def getDetails():
    while True:
        title = input("Enter item name: ")
        if title == 'quit':
            break
        cost = input("Enter item cost: ")
        item['title'] = title  #   adding an item to a dictionary looks just like
                            #   adding an item to a list, only with a textual
                            #   key instead of the index number.
        item['cost'] = cost
        inventory.append(item)
    return inventory

details = getDetails()
print("The dict returned was: ", details)
```

When I run the code, entering different items and their costs, I get the last item I entered as all the entries of the dictionary:

```
Enter item name: vacuum cleaner

Enter item cost: 199.95

Enter item name: mug

Enter item cost: 3.95

Enter item name: clock

Enter item cost: 12.95

Enter item name: quit
The dict returned was:  [{'title': 'clock', 'cost': '12.95'}, {'title': 'clock', 'cost': '12.95'}, {'title': 'clock', 'cost': '12.95'}]
```

Why isn't it adding the first dictionary to the list, then the next (different) one, then the next?

Comment: move `item = {}` to after `while True:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep adding the same item after making changes to it, which is why when you print the array, you see multiple copies of the "last" item you added (they aren't actually copies; they are separate references to the *same* item).  You need to create a new item each time through the `while` loop.